# Is it possible to record screen along with audio in android?

Tags: android, screen-recording

Is there any library to record audio+screen in android. I am making a tutorial helping application.

Comment: If u don't know the answer , stop inverting the answer.

Comment: I don't know about the screen, but you can't record the global audio output (unless you're happy with 8-bit audio, which you'd get from the `Visualizer` class).

Answer (score 0):

I think that recording the Android emulator is the easy way to go. There are plenty of open source screen recorders for your PC/Mac.

Comment: I want an standalone android application not an application in windows.